# How to make AutoCompleteTextView with history

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

Well, I already have an AutoCompleteTextView and it already shows some suggestions if I write it on the string.

But I liked that he remembered what the user has written.
See the follow example:

[Google Search History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wvm2.png)

This is my code so far:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, equipas);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView2.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private static final String[] equipas = new String[] {
        //Insert what the user writes!
};
```

**EDIT**

Here are the AutoCompleteTextView in the activity.xml:

[AutoCompleteTextView Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCFua.png)

**EDIT**

This is the full code:

```
package com.example.caca_a_frase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.caca_a_frase.Opcoes.som;
import static com.example.caca_a_frase.Opcoes.vibrar; 
import static com.example.caca_a_frase.SplashScreen.player;
import static com.example.caca_a_frase.Menus.shouldPlay;

public class Nomes extends Activity {

private static Button comecar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nomes);

    shouldPlay = false;

    onClickButtonListener();

    findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    //Atribuir o tipo de letra:
    Typeface peint = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "peinture_freiche.ttf");
    TextView equipum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    equipum.setTypeface(peint);
    TextView equipdois = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    equipdois.setTypeface(peint);
    //Acaba aqui!

    //Para ver a lista de nomes que já usaram:
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, equipas);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView2.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Acaba aqui!

}

private static final String[] equipas = new String[] {
        //Insert what the user writes!
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (shouldPlay == false){ //A música é parada se o "shouldPlay" for falso!
            player.pause();
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (shouldPlay == false){  //A música volta a ser tocada de onde estava se o "shouldPlay" for falso!
            player.start();
        }
        else {
            shouldPlay = false;
        }
    }

public void onClickButtonListener() {
    comecar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComecar);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
    comecar.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (som == true) {
                        mp2.start();
                       } if (vibrar == true) {
                        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vib.vibrate(100);
                       }
                    //Para ler o texto escrito:

                    EditText equipaum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText equipadois = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                    //Acaba aqui!
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.caca_a_frase.Game");
                    //Para guardar o texto com uma chave para outra atividade:

                    intent.putExtra("equipaum", equipaum.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("equipadois", equipadois.getText().toString());

                    //Acaba aqui!
                    shouldPlay = true;
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent voltar = new Intent("com.example.caca_a_frase.Menus");
    shouldPlay = true;
    startActivity(voltar);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

Comment: It needs to be an EditText

Comment: You mean an AutoCompleteTextView? I'm not sure that really matters.

Comment: Every time you enter some input, you add that value to the adapter. That creates your history... Don't use an array. Use a list

Comment: Can I input a listview into an AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: Why do you need a ListView?

Comment: I need an AutoCompleteTextView that shows the last words that the user wrote

Comment: I understand that. And when you "write" and submit, you just add to the adapter...

Comment: Yeap. That's what I want

Comment: Hard to see the rest of your code, but I already answered below with that

Comment: I already tested and it crashes when I start the application

Comment: "it crashes" doesn't describe the issue clearly enough for me to help you

Comment: I edited the question, it has now the full code, do you need the activity.xml too?

Comment: If something "crashes", the [logcat will tell you what reason your app has stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). Please [edit] your question with it.

Comment: Also, your Mediaplayer is not a [mcve] of your question, so please remove it

Answer (score 0):

`equipas` needs to be an Arraylist

If you call `adapter.add("value")`, then "value" will be in your suggestions / history.

Comment: Ok. I fixed the problem of crashing and added `adapter.add("value")` to test it. But now it continues not showing what I wrote.

Comment: Well, `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` seems to be unrelated to your AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: I fixed that problem, and tested the `adapter.add("value")` to see if it works, but it continues not showing anything.

Comment: For `equipas`, did you make it an arraylist instead of an array? I don't see why it wouldn't work. Then again, I haven't tried...

Comment: Yes, I converted `equipas` to an `ArrayList`